# How can i download image from local network PC with c#?

Tags: c#

I'm write this code for download image from local Pc:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile("BEHZAD-PC" + query[0].imgurl, "c:/foodimage/" + label1.Text + ".jpg");
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/foodimage/" + label1.Text + ".jpg");
            }
```

but now download,what happen?
my foodimage folder picture is there:
[image]

Comment: do you have any exception? Maybe `@"\\BEHZAD-PC\"` is the correct network path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if the file really exists? I also recommend using `Path.Combine` for any combination of path sequences. Another thing I noticed was you are using a `/` instead of `\\` or `@\`.

So please try the following code sequence:

```
//using System.IO;

string path = Path.Combine(@"\\BEHZAD-PC\foodimage", label1.Text, ".jpg");
if (File.Exists(path)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = path;
}
```

Comment: But where is the my pc on the network?,i want the pc1 download from behzad-pc image

Comment: add your code,but in this line File.Exist not work and into the if block not run

Comment: @elnazirani the above code works fine for me, tested it with my home server. do you have the right to access the folder from another computer?

Comment: how to test to access the file from other pc?